# Power BI Service not refreshing from SharePoint Excel file

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery

I have a Power BI report linked to an Excel file on SharePoint. I created the report on Power BI Desktop and then published it.

I am getting the data from Get Data -> From SharePoint Folder, I paste my site URL and login with my organization account. Then I filter for a specific Excel file, load and create some visuals.

I am using the same Power BI account to access the SharePoint folder. I went to Power BI Service settings of my dataset and set the same credentials to access the data source (Excel on SharePoint).
When my Excel file gets new data, I go to Power BI Service and click refresh on the dataset and I don't see the new data reflected on the report.

On the desktop version, refreshing will show new/changes in data. If I don't re-publish my report, I won't see any updates online.

What is missing?

I want to be able to refresh my reports from PBI Service directly from SharePoint.

**EDIT:**
Also tried Get data->Web, then pasting the Excel path copied from Inside Excel -> Info -> Copy Path.
Same process works on Desktop, but refreshing the dataset online does nothing. Connection to the data source is successful.

Comment: You need to activate your credentials and make sure it connects properly. You could be using an on-prem SharePoint site which isn't allowed in Power BI Service.

Comment: My credentials are correct and the connection is made successfully, it's SharePoint online. My organization has "Microsoft 365 Business Basic" subscription.